# Node await not waiting for promise

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, nodes

I have a promise that I'm trying to await but it is not working.

Here's my method:

```
async function lookupAndAddManager(id, record, fieldNameToAdd) {
    console.log(`Searching ${id}`);
    let promise = ups.getSearchResults(ups.Environment.Prod, ups.SearchConfig.Email, ups.emailFromId(id))
    console.log("Promise", promise)
    let response = await promise;
}
```

I'm calling it like this:

`lookupAndAddManager(row.BPO, row, 'BPO_MGR')`

My output is:

> > Searching CN=Name/OU=TEST/O=EXAMPLE
> >
> > Promise Promise {  }

However, the method is returning right away, the `await promise` does not wait for the promise to be resolved.

Why not?

The method I'm calling is also async:

```
export const getSearchResults = async (env: Environment, searchConfig: SearchConfig, query: string): Promise<ISearchResult> => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        ... resolve/reject as appropriate ...
    });
};
```

Comment: `await lookupAndAddManager(row.BPO, row, 'BPO_MGR')` You should call it like this as well. It returns a promise.

Comment: It's an async method, so, of course, it will return right away...unless you await lookupAndAddManager too in the function that calls it.  That's how async works.

Comment: just to confirm you are using await to call your async function lookupAndAddManager, right?

Comment: No, I'm calling `lookupAndAddManager` from my main entry point, so it's not being called from an async method. I have to, at some point, call the method from a non-async method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: See the aforementioned [suggested duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/1260204). Asynchronous calls are a common and critical building block in writing/designing an application. It is critical that you understand how to work with asynchronous calls in javascript. Understanding these core concepts will help you become a better programmer and also ensure you do not keep "stubbing your toe" on the same problem.

Comment: @mikeb on what basis you are saying it is not awaiting? and also there is a chance that you are not resolving promise properly from getSearchResults causing the probel.

Answer (score 1):

There is some other issue. I simulated your code and the await works fine.

```js
async function lookupAndAddManager(id, record, fieldNameToAdd) {
    console.log(`Searching ${id}`);
    let promise = getSearchResults();
    console.log("Promise will be promised and then wait 3 seconds, now its just unresolved promise object", promise)
    let response = await promise;
    console.log("After 3 seconds, we got response", response);
}

const getSearchResults = async (env, searchConfig, query) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve('Yeeey, resolved'), 3000);
    });
};

lookupAndAddManager(10);
```